Как по полученному адресу вывести значение ячейки в Excel?
Я получил Адрес ячейки по формуле (введена в ячейку Q2):
=АДРЕС(2;11)  # $K$2

Эта функция возвращает адрес. А как теперь мне по полученному адресу получить значение?
UPD:
Через ИНДЕКС Выводит тоже адрес, а не значение
=ИНДЕКС(Q2;1;1)


ДВССЫЛ(). А вообще, такой подход зачастую неправильный. И АДРЕС(), и ДВССЫЛ() - текстовые функции, а вторая еще и летучая. Задача в чем состоит? Еще до получения адреса?

Спасибо, то что надо. А сама задача чуть сложнее была - мне просто последний этап нужен был. Я искал значение, есть ли оно в диапазоне данных и если есть, то мне надо было вывести относительно этой записи значение из другого столбца

Есть одна из самых быстрых функций - ИНДЕКС. Совсем не обязательно использовать АДРЕС, которая обязует применить тормознутую ДВССЫЛ
=ДВССЫЛ(АДРЕС(2;11))

АДРЕС текстовая (медленная), ДВССЫЛ тоже с тормозами. А еще она волатильная, т.е. вызывает пересчет при любом изменении на листе. А еще - не работает с закрытыми книгами.
Эту кашу можно спокойно заменить на
=ИНДЕКС(1:5;2;11)

Здесь диапазон выбрать, исходя из условий задачи.
